# Add multiple constant value in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I have a problem in my php script.
This is the script

```
<?php 
    define("BASE_URL", "http://external.site/xxx/API.php");
    define("APIKEY", "46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7","7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8");

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $api_key = APIKEY;
?>
```

The problem is when my clients access the second key which is `7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8` the first key(`46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7`) is being charged,

How can I add multiple keys so each key(whichever is requested) is charged separately?

Thanks.

Comment: make it strict that they only use one api key - why would you define different passwords in one password field? it just makes no sense

Comment: You can assign the values as constant array. But, you need to change the API key handling mechanism accordingly. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: First, having a look at the [PHP: define - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), your syntax is totally wrong. In the sense, the syntax doesn't accept two values. Where did you even get that idea of adding two and expecting PHP to handle two values. That's completely wrong.

Comment: if you are using php7 you can define the const as array http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php#121601

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm very much a newbie to PHP. I just got an idea, that it might work. BTW, I want to have multiple API keys to work, so that my clients can request a GET to my server using the API which I give them. Using only one API which has a balance will be a problem since User1 may request only one credit and User2 may request ten credits. Ultimately, 11 credits will be charged and I'll not have a proper count.

So is there something that I can do?

Comment: I mean if someone is sending a GET to mysite.com/API.php?api_key=7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8...

It is behaving as if 46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7 has sent a GET request and 46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7 is being charged, even though 7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8 is using the API.

Answer (score 2):

`define()` accepts only 2 parameters, not 3.

You can use an array. You have 2 possibilities :

```
const APIKEY = ['46B067...','7285e8...']; // PHP 5.6+
// OR
define('APIKEY', ['46B067...','7285e8...']); // PHP 7+

// THEN
echo APIKEY[0]; // Access 1st key => 46B067...
echo APIKEY[1]; // Access 2nd key => 7285e8...
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and see. Also is there a way to define more than 2 keys?

Comment: I tried doing this but I'm getting a BADKEY response which is a server response which happens when server thinks that the apikey is wrong.

Comment: I don't want it to get public. So is there a way to share the code via PM?

Comment: @mdhz You can define more keys under one Constant by using an `associative array` as the `second parameter` in the `define` function. I have posted a solution with the same.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use `const` or `define`. It all depends on what you want to do.

So you can do use const (`PHP 5.6+`)

```
const APIKEY = ['46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7','7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8'];
```

Or use define (`PHP 7+`)

```
define("APIKEY", ['46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7','7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8']);
```

Getting the values

```
echo APIKEY[0]; // To get the 1st key => 46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7
echo "<br/>"; // Line break
echo APIKEY[1]; // To get the 2nd key => 7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8
```

If you want to have more constants within the definition, you can use `define` passing an associative array as the second argument. (`PHP 7+`)

```
define(
    "APIKEY", array(
        "KEY_1" => "46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7",
        "KEY_2" => "7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8",
        "KEY_n+1" => "") // As many as you want
);
```

To get your keys

```
echo APIKEY['KEY_1']; // To get the 1st key 46B067078483416eBedB2f8005586eB7
echo "<br/>"; // Line break
echo APIKEY['KEY_2']; // To get the 1st key 7285e87c1c7Ac16c5870A4cf5cf166f8
```